# loading data after loading view in iphone application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

Hi I am new to objective c. I am trying to create a login system app.

Here is how my story board looks like:

[image]

I will be using AFNetworking classes and rest php library to talk with data.

Now as you can see i created navigations for my first app using push, modal and navigation.

Where i am stucked

When user click on sign in button in app the app first will authorise user and then will take user to find places view.

What i need is when i click on sign in button, first the place finder view will open and then will call function which will display data of places using rest api eith json format.

```
 - (IBAction)signin:(id)sender {
  [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"landingView" sender:sender];
  }


- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

   if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"landingView"]) {
   // what i do here to call function -"display_place" of class -"showplaces"????

   }
 }
```

I hope i can get some idea if i am going right or what i should do next?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the destinationViewController property from the segue:

```
 - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

   if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"landingView"]) {
      [((showplaces *)segue.destinationViewController) display_places];
   }
 }
```

By the way, you are not using proper naming of classes and functions... You should take a look at other examples and tutorials to see how is the code style for Objective C.

Comment: Here is what i getting after doing what you said. 
No visible @interface for 'showplaces' declares the selector 'display_place'

Comment: to access to a class function, it need to be imported on the top of your class (#import "showplaces.h"). Also, make sure that "display_place" is declared in your showplaces.h

Comment: @Adhaata I don't see your edit. However, if this question is answered and you have more questions, you should close this one and open a new one :)

Comment: i have opened new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16576650/loading-data-in-second-view-controller-in-xcode-nslog