# Loading data in second view controller in xcode NSLog

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios4

I am quite new to object C and iphone app development.

**Here is what I have:
StoryBoard**

[image]

**What I have done**

1. Dragged button to first view controller.
2. Dragged second view controller.
3. Added push animation
4. Editor >> Embed in >> Navigation controller

**Here is my Code:**

[image]

Now i added, a class of objective C, class with name dResult subclass of NSObject.

**My question is**

I want to place a function viewDidLoad within class dResult, and then execute it when second view controller loads once someone click on "show next".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you want, you want to do something like this in the second view controller's viewDidLoad method:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    dResult *dResultObject = [[dResult alloc] init];
    [deResultObject someMethodIHaveInDResult];
}
```

Where someMethodIHaveInDResult is a method the you've implemented in the dResult class. It's not clear what you mean by "function viewDidLoad within class dResult" -- dResult isn't a view controller, so it doesn't have a viewDidLoad method, and I would make a method in there called that, because it would be confusing.

Comment: Hi @rdelmar, thanks for answer. I know my question in bit confusig and its only coz i am new. We can take example of website, lets think we are on page "Home".. now i clicked on link "About us".  In about us page we have a jquery document ready function to alert something. Your code example is calling a function "someMethodIHaveInDResult" on viewDidLoad of class first viewcontroller.but i want some code execute once second view is on screen and ready.

Comment: @Adhaata, my answer said to put this code in the second controller, not the first. If you actually want it not to execute until it's on screen, you could put the code in viewDidAppear instead.